Как заставить 2х ботов работать на одном сервере?
Бот для парсинга данных с  сайтов и отправления сводки в тг группу.
Если запустить на одном сервере с разными bot_token, то есть один бот отправляет в одну группу, другой чуть по другому в другую.
Запуск первого - все ок.
Запускаю второй, все работает до момента отправить сообщение(видимо начинает парсить).
То есть кто первый сделал парсинг, тот и будет работать, второй уже не сможет.
Я не силен в этом,как можно поправить доступным языком пожалуйста?

Попробуйте запустить ботов отдельно и посмотреть на результаты. Так же скиньте ошибки, которые у вас возникают в ходе работы ботов. В них должна быть информация, почему бот прекращает работу

По отдеkьности все ок работают, они одинаковые. Можно даже запустить сразу 2, но парсить и отправить сообщение в группу будет только один(кто первый начал с момента запуска) . Была такая вот ошибка 'rror sending test post: Page.click: Target crashed
Call log:
waiting for locator("li.menu-item:has-text("Binance")")' сейчас такая 'Error sending test post: Page.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
Call log:
waiting for locator("li.menu-item:has-text("Binance")")'

Почему вы не можете просто сделать два скрипта и заставить их работать отдельно?
Если необходимо заставить работать два телеграмм-бота на одном скрипте, то можно сделать следующее:
bot1 = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN 1')

bot2 = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN 2')

YOUR_BOT_TOKEN 1 замените на токен первого бота, а  YOUR_BOT_TOKEN 2 - на токен второго. В таком случае события будут начинаться следующим образом:
@bot1.message_handler(content_types=['text']) #Пример полученя текста для первого бота

@bot2.message_handler(content_types=['text']) #Пример получения текста для второго бота

P.S. Чуть не забыл, что также для каждого бота нужно будет добавить:
bot1.infinity_polling();
bot2.infinity_polling()


Один бот запущен и управление им предоставлено другому человеку, он там сам меняет как ему хочется(например, включает или выключает openrouter для редактирования). Второй бот с другими настройками под управлением другого человека и в другой канал. Не каких виртуальных сред не делал, просто сервер с python. Может для 1 сделать виртуальную среду и это поможет?
